# Conditional data validation for MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i read some tutorials that help out with conditional (or dynamic) data validation, but its usually dynamically generating list item choices based on previous selection etc.

what i want is, lets say i have

```
columnA : columnB
telephone_number : 911
name: peterparker
```

is it possible for me to dynamically specify data validation rules on columnB based on what is selected in columnA? if its telephone_number, i want to check that the corresponding cell in columnB is a natural number, and if it is a name,i want to check for a string for a certain length. of course i limit the string options that the user can input in columnA.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can build an array in VBA, and use the array as the source of the validation list.

Comment: Use formula based validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to ***data validation*** is ***Conditional Formatting***. The benefit of the latter is that it is more versatile. We can have the following setting:

[image]

Then if we define a name, `DynamicValidation` as follows:

[image]

the formula at the validation box is

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet1!$D$2:$E$3,2,0),"()","("&ADDRESS(ROW(),2)&")"))
```

`EVALUATE` cannot be used in any sheet cell, ***but*** it can be used in Named ranges. However, you will have to save your book as macro-enabled, because it is a legacy macro, originating from `Excel 4.0`. What it does is the following:

- Looks at the value in `List1` and finds the formula that needs to be checked (`VLOOKUP`).
- Subtitutes `"()"` with the cell value of interest (and adds back the parentheses).

Then if you open a conditional formatting box (`Home` tab, `Conditional Formatting`, `New Rule`, `Use a formula to determine....`) and input the formula `=Not(DynamicValidation)` like this:

[image]

then each cell that does not adhere to the formula will turn red. I tried that with data validation as well, but it does not work unless we build the depencency tree every time we change `List 2`.. I am not sure why.. But only conditional formatting works :) Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The benefit is that we can change the validation criteria without hard-coding.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Following formula on custom validation rules will do:

```
=IF(A1="telephone_number";ISNUMBER(B1);IF(A1="name";LEN(B1)=8;TRUE))
```

This is example for cell in `B1`. You may choose a wider range and combine `$` to adapt you formula to all range.